# i want my code to output something like "example = .-.-.-.-" but rather it outputs "example = .- = .- = .- = .-"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made some code that makes English encrypted to morse, and I wanted it to output something like "example = .-.-.-.-" but rather it outputs "example = .- = .- = .- = .-"
ive tried searching on google but no luck
my code:

```
def reset ():

cheat_sheet = { 'A':'.-', 'B':'-...', 
                    'C':'-.-.', 'D':'-..', 'E':'.', 
                    'F':'..-.', 'G':'--.', 'H':'....', 
                    'I':'..', 'J':'.---', 'K':'-.-', 
                    'L':'.-..', 'M':'--', 'N':'-.', 
                    'O':'---', 'P':'.--.', 'Q':'--.-', 
                    'R':'.-.', 'S':'...', 'T':'-', 
                    'U':'..-', 'V':'...-', 'W':'.--', 
                    'X':'-..-', 'Y':'-.--', 'Z':'--..', 
                    '1':'.----', '2':'..---', '3':'...--', 
                    '4':'....-', '5':'.....', '6':'-....', 
                    '7':'--...', '8':'---..', '9':'----.', 
                    '0':'-----', ', ':'--..--', '.':'.-.-.-', 
                    '?':'..--..', '/':'-..-.', '-':'-....-', 
                    '(':'-.--.', ')':'-.--.-'}


d = input ('what would you like to encrypt')

def morse_encrypter (placeholder):
    cache = d
    for letter in placeholder:
        cache += ' = '
        cache += cheat_sheet [letter]
    return cache


def DO_THE_THING(): 
    placeholder = d
    the_answer = morse_encrypter(placeholder.upper()) 
    print (the_answer)

DO_THE_THING ()

restart = input ('would you like to reset?')
if restart == 'y' or restart == 'yes':
    reset()   
if restart == 'n' or restart == 'no':
    print ('goodbye')
```

reset ()

Comment: This line `cache += ' = '` is adding all of those unwanted `=` signs isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cache += ' = '` was in the loop, causing the error.

```
def morse_encrypter (placeholder):
    cache = d
    cache += ' = '
    for letter in placeholder:
        cache += cheat_sheet [letter]
    return cache
```

Comment: yes but i want it to have an equals sign between the morse, and the word

Comment: Have you tried using this implementation?

Comment: omg that worked thx!